# no results elasticsearch when query by multi_field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping on my index in elasticsearch.

```
{
"mail": {
    "properties": {
        "project": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "na",
            "include_in_all": "false"
        },
        "mailbox": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "#na",
            "store" : "yes"
        },
        "path": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "#na",
            "store" : "yes"
        },
        "messageid": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "na",
            "include_in_all": "false"
        },
        "nodeid":
        {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "na",
            "include_in_all": "false",
            "store" : "yes"
        },
        "replyto": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "na",
            "include_in_all": "false"
        },
        "references": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "null_value": "na",
            "include_in_all": "false"
        },
        "subject": {
            "boost": "3.0",
            "type": "string",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
        },
        "from": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type" : "multi_field",
                    "fields" : {
                        "name" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "standard", "index" : "analyzed"},
                        "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                    }
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_email"
                },
                "nodeid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                },
                "facet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                }
            }
        },
        "to": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties":{
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_email"
                },
                "nodeid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                },
                "facet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                }
            }
        },
        "cc": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties":{
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_email"
                },
                "nodeid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                },
                "facet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                }
            }
        },
        "bcc": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties":{
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_email"
                },
                "nodeid": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                },
                "facet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                }
            }
        },
        "message_snippet": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no",
            "include_in_all": "false"
        },
        "text_messages": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": "yes",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
        },
        "html_messages": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": "yes",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
        },
        "message_attachments": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties":{
                "filename":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "content":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                    "analyzer": "snowball"
                },
                "hash":{
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "nodeid":{
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "date": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "entities": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "nodeid":{
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "facet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store" : "yes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I try searching on the mail.from.name field with the following query, but I doesn't give me any results.

```
 {
 "query": {
 "nested": {
  "path": "from",
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "mark"
    }
  }
 }
}
}
```

What is wrong about my mapping or query?

A sample document looks like this

```
{
  "project": "test",
  "mailbox": "test.pst",
  "messageid": "5e667f7f-4421-4836-91f3-8b5216c04839",
  "nodeid": "671",
  "subject": "No Subject",
  "from": [
    {
      "name": "Mike Johnson",
      "address": "mike@gmail.com",
      "nodeid": "3",
      "facet": "Mike Johnson"
    }
  ],
  "to": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "address": "JDoe@gmail.com",
      "nodeid": "367",
      "facet": "John Doe"
    }
  ],
  "cc": [],
  "bcc": [],
  "textbody": "this is a test email with no further lines of text",
  "htmlbody": "",
  "snippet": "",
  "transmitted": "",
  "replyto": "",
  "references": "",
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "google",
      "type": "organization",
      "nodeid": "656",
      "facet": "google"
    }
  ],
  "domains": [
    "google.com"
  ],
  "path": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address the [nested objects](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) name in your query again

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "from",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "from.name": "mike"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```